# Multiple carousels on webpage with different timers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have 4 different carousels all on the same webpage, the first one needs to go much quicker than the others, I tried separating the scripts, but at the moment they all go at this faster speed:

```
<script>
    $('.carousel, #carosuel-one').carousel({
        interval: 1000,
        pause: "none",
    });
</script>

<script>
    $('#carousel-two, #carousel-three, #carousel-four').carousel({
        interval: 6000,
        pause: "none",
    });
</script>
```

Comment: call the carousel slider with seprate id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is there a class mentioned in the first init. Is that a common class for all your carousels.

```
$('.carousel, #carosuel-one').carousel({
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/2297/)

Answer (score 1):

You should try this

```
<script>
    $(' #carosuel-one').carousel({
    interval: 1000,
    pause: "none",
    });

    $('#carousel-two').carousel({
    interval: 4000,
    pause: "none",
    });

    $('#carousel-three').carousel({
    interval: 8000,
    pause: "none",
    });

    $('#carousel-four').carousel({
    interval: 10000,
    pause: "none",
    });
</script>
```

Comment: They're all still going at the same speed.

Comment: That's alright, removed the carosuel classes from each and works now, thanks!